Twilio Service Instance Not Found
I've been trying to run an AI-Assistant for a while now. I follow the below tutorial and I get to the same part, then i get the same error. I've tried it every way i can think of.
I'm running Linux on local with twilio-cli. I'm working with the Conversations interface for the Twilio AI-Assistant.
twilio api:conversations:v1:conversations:create --friendly-name "My First Conversation"
 » Error code 50050 from Twilio: Service instance not found. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/50050 for more info.

It can't find this Service instance. I login with Twilio and enter my Account ID, Auth ID and profile name. It never asks me for the instance SID at this point in the tutorial so i understand why it can't find the Service. Is this a docs issue?
https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart
When I try the alternative Codesandbox method, i run into another error - "identity option needs to be supplied". I have no idea at this point.
Can I install Twilio dependencies in CodeSandbox? I've been running the above command locally with the Twilio-cli installed.
i'm finding the docs hard to interpret. Maybe it's just me though.
